# Selenium driver won't start after the first test - IntelliJ

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Seleium4 with IntelliJ and I get this error after the 1st test run. The first run works fine but after the browser quits, it errors on trying to spin up another one. Wish it didn't work at all, would be easier to troubleshoot but the fcat it works once, then fails after that has me stumped. Worse even is that people who are using Myclipse with the same code have no issues. ugg. Any ideas would be appreciated. thanks

tarting ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.71 (9729082fe6174c0a371fc66501f5efc5d69d3d2b-refs/branch-heads/6099_56@{#13}) on port 41889
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'M00436431', ip: '192.168.0.19'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)

expect Selenium driver to open for each test